# Compare oracle date in query with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, date, datetime

I want to compare dates retrieved from oracle database in php. but i don't know how to convert month name like Sep to SEP. I don't know how to convert month in capital letters. I want to convert 2015-09-01 formate to 03-SEP-15.

```
      //sDate: 2015-09-01 eDate: 2015-09-03

$date1=date('d-M-Y', strtotime($sDate));
$date2=date('d-M-Y', strtotime($eDate));

// CREATEDATE: 03-SEP-15 02.44.42.000000 PM
```

QUERY:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CAST(CREATEDATE AS DATE)  between   '".$sDate."' AND  '".$eDate."'");
```

ERROR:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Comment: Please can you make your question a bit more clear

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can convert a string into a date using the to_date() function. And a date to a string using the to_char() function

Example

```
to_date('01-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

will return a value of type date.

Now, in your query you must make sure that the values in your "between" statement are date values. The only way to ensure that is to make $sDate a atring value and use the to_date function.
Assuming that your date strings are in format 01-JAN-2015...

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 
  "SELECT * 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE CAST(CREATEDATE AS DATE)  
   between  to_date('".$sDate."','DD-MON-YYYY') 
   AND  to_date('".$eDate."','DD-MON-YYYY')");
```

See also the Oracle documentation on date formats.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 0):

So you have a date string like this: '2015-09-01' and you want to convert it to '01-09-2015' to be used in a query.

If you want to debug if the issue is in how you handle the date conversion in php try to do:

```
list($year,$month,$day)=explode('-',$date);
$months = ['','JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC'];

$date = implode('-',$day,$months[$month],$year);
```

Then try to run the query. You don't need to take the string, convert it into a date (unix timestamp) and convert it back to a string if you just need to change the order of the elements in the date. You have to follow your approach if you want to manipulate your date adding or removing some time or stuffs like that.

If the query is still in error and you are sure that dates in your db are stored with that pattern than the issue is in the query syntax

Comment: edited my answer. Please check the month names in the array if they are what expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison calculations in the Oracle query without having to format any PHP or Oracle dates. For example, if I want to compare a stored date to sysdate, I do something like :

```
select date1, date2 - sysdate as date2 from table1;
```

It will return a real number representing the time date. Then the PHP to compare would simply be something like :

```
If ($date1 < $date 2 ) {
   Do stuff;
}
```